# Using JQuery functions in my external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to web programming and would like some help figuring out how files are linked together and such. I was originally planning to only use plain Javascript for my website, but I recently caved in and decided to use the JQuery library (after admitting defeat on spending hours making my own JS functions lol). I have a file `jsfunctions.js` in the File Manager section of my web hosting service. That's the location of all my JavaScript functions I've  used so far. I plan on adding some that call JQuery functions. I uploaded `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` into my file manager and now I'm wondering how to write functions in my `jsfunctions.js` that call functions from `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`. Do I have to use sort of include at the top of `jsfunctions.js`???

Comment: Load jQuery before that file, then use jQuery

Answer (score 2):

As long as jQuery is loaded before your external script, you'll have access to jQuery within your files.

```
<script src="jquery"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

`myScript.js` has access to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery creates a global object that is available to all of the scripts running on your page. That's why you don't need any kind of `require` or `include` code to use it. Like everyone is saying, if you just make sure jQuery loads before your other scripts, all of those scripts will automatically have access to `jQuery` as a global variable.